# $this-Session->destroy() is not destroying the session? v. cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp

my UserController.php has logout function that looks like this

```
 function logout()
    {
        $this->Session->destroy('User'); 
        $this->Session->setFlash('You\'ve successfully logged out.');
        var_export($this->Session->read('User'));

        //$this->redirect('login'); 
    }
```

my view Users/index.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout')); ?>
```

When I click "log out" the var_export still displays all the User data and if I go back to Users/index.ctp it still shows me that page even though in my my UserController.php I am checking if User is set

```
    function beforeFilter() 
{   
    $this->__validateLoginStatus(); 
}   


function __validateLoginStatus() 
    {   
        if($this->action != 'login' && $this->action != 'logout') 
        {
            if($this->Session->check('User') == false)
            {
                $this->redirect('login');
            }
        }
```

It does not redirect to login page and just brings me to index page.
        }

Comment: $this->Session->destroy('User');  It will also work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->Session->destroy();
```

The destroy method will delete the session cookie and all session data stored in the temporary file system.

User to remove, use better delete.

```
$this->Session->delete('User');
```

Comment: What's the difference between $this->Session->delete('User') and $this->Session->destroy('User');

Comment: $this->Session->delete() empty a Session, and $this->Session->destroy() destroy the PHP session and then create a fresh session.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the AuthComponent to authenticate the users, you can log them out by using the logout() method.

```
$this->Auth->logout();
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#logging-users-out for Cake 2 or http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1262/logout for Cake 1.3

And if you don't use the AuthComponent at all, you should maybe have a look at it as it contains out of the box many functionalities that you have already or will likely implement yourself.